# getting error missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not an expert in Python as I am trying to gain knowledge. I am trying to resolve an error while executing the code. The code builds a JSON and validates and then posts the valid JSON to an app using a bearer token. I am passing all the arguments to the function and initializing the class but still getting the error.
I am getting error- `parseJSON() missing 1 required positional argument: 'eventData'`
Any pointers on what I am doing wrong? Do I need to pass self elsewhere?

```
import json
import datetime
import hashlib
import json
import sys
import traceback 
import adal
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry


class Link(object):
    # class APIAlerting:
    cloudtest = TokenLibrary.getSecret("A", "B")
    cloudclient = TokenLibrary.getSecret("C", "D")
    clientid = TokenLibrary.getSecret("E", "F")
    clientcredentials = TokenLibrary.getSecret("G", "H")
    authority_url = TokenLibrary.getSecret("I", "J")

    _token = None
    _instance = None
    http = None

    @staticmethod
    def getInstance():

        if not Link._instance:
            Link._instance = Link()

        return Link._instance

    def __init__(self):

        retry_strategy = Retry(
            total=3,
            backoff_factor=0,
            status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504],
            allowed_methods=["HEAD", "GET", "OPTIONS"],
        )
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)
        self.http = requests.Session()
        self.http.mount("https://", adapter)
        self.http.mount("http://", adapter)
        print("Inside init")

    def parseJSON(self, t):
        try:
            eventData = json.loads(self.t)
            sendToEvent(eventData)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(
                "Error: %s Please validate JSON in https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/"
                % e
            )
            return None  # or: raise

    def sendToEvent(self, eventData):
        cloudData = {"eventData": self.eventData}
        logger.info(f"Raising alert with data=({cloudData}")
        response = self.http.post(
            cloudtest, headers=headers, json=cloudData
        )
        logger.info(f"cloud boss alert response={response}")
  

    def _buildJSONdata(self,Data):
        if len(self.Data) == 0:
            raise Exception("JSON is empty")
        else:
            t = json.dumps(self.Data)
            parseJSON(t)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Data = {"A": "Name"}
    apiAlert = Link()
    apiAlert._buildJSONdata(Data)
```

Comment: ```self.parseJSON(t)``` should fixed your problem

Comment: Thanks.Now I am getting Link' object has no attribute 't'

Comment: ```eventData = json.loads(t)``` should fixed that too.